# Oracle/SQL - Split list into 3 segments

Tags: sql, oracle, segment

I'm wondering how I would go about writing a query to split a table into 3 segments.  When I've had to split a table into 2 before I've always based it off the rownum and doing a mod on it.  I know I could again use rownum and select based on ranges, but if the list varies in record count each time the queries are run they will have to be updated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't want to partition the table.. I just need to create 3 views that will each pull out 33% of the list.  I was hoping there was a better way to do it than using rownum < and > than such and such so that as the table scales the queries won't have to be re-written.

Comment: Why won't `mod` work with 3 - if it worked with 2?

Comment: @dscl: why not use partitioning?  you would then do: select * from mytable partition(some_partition_name);  easy, maintains itself, and yes it scales.

Comment: Partitioning does require enterprise edition plus extra fees, perhaps that could factor in.

Comment: Mod wont work because my feeble brain was malfunctioning.  Sorry for wasting time on such an easy one, but the ol noggin was spiraling down wrong tangents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you continue to use MOD, as in MOD(rownum, 3) = 0, 1 or 2? If it worked for 2, why not 3?